# tkinter change style questions

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Right now I have this code:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview", foreground='#00337f',background="#ffc61e")
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", background="purple",foreground='#00337f',font=(20))
tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three")
tree.column("one", width=150)
tree.column("two", width=150)
tree.column("three", width=210)
tree.heading("one", text="Naar")
tree.heading("two", text="Spoor")
tree.heading("three", text="Vetrektijd")
tree.tag_configure('monospace', font=20)
tree['show'] = 'headings'
tree.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Everything works fine except 3 things:

- Whenever I run the program the treeview background is still white but it needs to be yellow from the beginning. Right now it becomes yellow whenever the treeview is filled.
- The second problem is that I changed the background of the heading to purple as you can see in the code above but it still is white. So how can I make it purple?
- The third problem is there is still a line after the treeview is filled:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem can be solved by adding `fieldbackground="#ffc61e"` in the configuration of the `Treeview` style. The background option corresponds to the background of the items only. However, not all themes takes the `fieldbackground` option into account (see the second problem).

The second problem is theme related. The theme you are using does not support color change for the headings, so I suggest you to use another one like 'clam' or 'alt': `style.theme_use('clam')`.

To remove the borders of the buttons in the heading, you can set the border width to 0: 
`style.configure("Treeview.Heading", borderwidth=0)`.

Unfortunately, this does not work for the Treeview border, so the solution is to set all colors of the border to the background color:

```
style.configure("Treeview", lightcolor="#ffc61e", bordercolor="#ffc61e",
                darkcolor="#ffc61e")
```

Comment: hi.
I tried your fieldbackground thing but it only become yellow one i insert something inside the table. not from the start i need that hte background is yellow from the start
at the beginning the background is still white

Comment: @Klaas It does not work with every theme, try changing the theme first.

Comment: thanks got it working now. by the 3th problem i mean this:
http://nl.tinypic.com/r/28ti3wz/9
it shows a white line around it. i need that to be yellow too

Comment: this is my final question hhope you can help me?