# How correctly to set treeview row foreground and background colors

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a problem setting the foreground and background colors for ttk.Treeview.

I have tried using tag_configure but that doesn't seem to work either. I have some mockup code (below) that I'm using to figure this out.
It's possible to change the header colors but not the rows, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview, Style


class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.container = Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.tree()

    def tree(self):
        style = Style()

        tv = Treeview(self.container)
        tv.grid(sticky='NSEW')

        tv.insert('', '0', 'item1', text='Item 1', tags='row')
        tv.insert('', '1', 'item2', text='Item 2', tags='row')
        tv.insert('', '2', 'item3', text='Item 3', tags='row')

        tv.insert('item1', '0', 'python1', text='Python Treeview1')
        tv.insert('item1', '1', 'python2', text='Python Treeview2')

        tv.insert('python1', '0', 'thon1', text='Treeview1')
        tv.insert('python1', '1', 'thon2', text='Treeview2')

        tv.heading(f'#{0}',  text='Title')
        style.configure(
            "Treeview.Heading",
            padding=5,
            borderwidth=0,
        )

        style.configure(
            "Treeview",
            foreground='red',
            background="black",
            fieldbackground='blue'
        )
        tv.tag_configure('row', foreground='red')


def main():
    root = Tk()

    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    App(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Read [configuration of the Treeview style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46971402/7414759)

Comment: Nothing there was of help still can't get the tree rows to change from black text on a white background. I know there is a method called tag_configure(). I used that to try and get the colors to change but no luck. I have looked at other posts and they seem to be pointing toward tag_configure(). Thank you for your response.

Comment: You have to do `style.configure(...` **before** `tv = Treeview(...`

Comment: This might be related to [this tcl/tk bug](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview?name=509cafafae)

Comment: Thank you I found a fix from the link you sent me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the Tcl/tk library as noted in the comments from, https://stackoverflow.com/users/7414759/stovfl.