# Change colour in a row in Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

In the following Python code I try to change the colour of rows in the Treeview table. It doesn't work. I try with tag.configure but... 
As you can see what the function do is extract data from a sql database and put it in a Treeview table, depending line the colour should be different but it doesn't work... anu help?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

root=Tk()

FrameTabla=Frame(root)
FrameTabla.pack()
def mostrar_items():


    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("database")
    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()


    miCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATABASE ORDER BY USERID DESC")

    lista=miCursor.fetchall()

    for i in lista:


        if lista.index(i) % 2 == 0:
            Tabla.insert('', 0, text=i[0], values=(i[1], i[2]), tags=('par',))


        else: 
            Tabla.insert('', 0, text=i[0], values=(i[1], i[2]), tags=('impar',))

    miConexion.close()



Tabla=ttk.Treeview(FrameTabla, heigh=20, columns=("Nombre", "Apellido"))
Tabla.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
Tabla.tag_configure('par',background='white',foreground='black')
Tabla.tag_configure('impar',background='black',foreground='white')
Tabla.heading('#0', text = 'UserID', anchor = CENTER)
Tabla.heading('Nombre', text = 'Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
Tabla.heading('Apellido', text = 'Apellido', anchor = CENTER)
Tabla.column('#0', width=120, anchor= CENTER)
Tabla.column('Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
Tabla.column('Apellido', anchor = CENTER)

ScrollVert=Scrollbar(FrameTabla, command=Tabla.yview)
ScrollVert.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='nsew')

mostrar_items()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you verified that your condition `if lista.index(i) % 2 == 0:` changes?

Comment: Relevant: [how-correctly-to-set-treeview-row-foreground-and-background-colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560784/how-correctly-to-set-treeview-row-foreground-and-background-colors)

Comment: Yes, I've checked printing different str and it works...

Comment: Well it seems that there's a bug in ttk library

Comment: Which version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Further to this issue I have seen a number of responses to getting the Treeview row colour to work but if your problem resides with the Style Theme Files and you are using Windows 10 then you will spend a great deal of time going around in circles not ever getting it to work which I did and which is why I have provided these additional comments.
1 - there are setup issues with the Theme Files in relation to Treeview colour displays.  Defined as a bug that has been / will be fixed in future releases.
2 - start point is to update the Theme File you are using in your program albeit I have seen an option to introduce some additional code to override the file issues. I found this harder to apply(and I didn't really understand what it was doing) than changing the Theme Files directly.
3 -  The address for the Theme Files for me is:
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\tcl\tk8.6\ttk
All the Theme files are named xxxxxTheme e.g clamTheme, vistaTheme etc.  The change needed was something I found on a python 'reported' bug site.  Below is the before change values which seem to be consistent in each Theme file:

```
ttk::style map Treeview \
        -background [list   disabled SystemButtonFace \
                {!disabled !selected} SystemWindow \
                selected SystemHighlight] \
        -foreground [list   disabled SystemGrayText \
                {!disabled !selected} SystemWindowText \
                selected SystemHighlightText]
```

After Changes follow - in essence you need to remove the disabled references

```
# Treeview: 
    ttk::style map Treeview \
        -background [list selected SystemHighlight] \
        -foreground [list selected SystemHighlightText]  \
        ;
```

This resolves the issue immediately you apply it but you need to ensure that you then use the Theme that you have amended, also make sure that you take a copy of the original theme file pre the changes as python wont run if you mess it up.
A couple of lines follow to setup use of the style that you have amended, in this case vista.

```
style = ttk.Style()      
style.theme_use('vista')
```

Happy to post a complete example of using the 'odd' and 'even' tag approach to alternating row colours for Treeview if needed but I think if you got to the point of the style and tags not working for colours then you were very close to completing on this anyway.